# How do I get the directory for the app itself in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, file-io

I have a .txt file in a Resources folder that I created in the Xamarin.Forms project for the app (not the Android or iOS versions), and I want to know how to access that file as soon as the app loads. I tried just creating a StreamReader with the path "Resources/tips.txt" ("tips" is the name of the file), but that doesn't work because apparently, the current directory at that point is nothing. How do I get the directory of the app itself so I can access that folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files#loading-files-embedded-as-resources) aren't files, you don't use file paths to access them

```
// MyClass is a class in the same assembly as your resource
var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(MyClass)).Assembly;

// see linked docs for notes about resource naming
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyResourceName");

string text = "";

using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream))
{  
    text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That fixed my problem (along with looking up some parts of it because I'm new to embedded resources).